# Populate treeview with - path enumeration

Tags: c#, treeview, enumeration

I'm trying to populate treeview with list od items. Item contain name and path:

Here is the code:

```
private void CreateTree(TreeNodeCollection nodeList, string path, string name)
    {
        TreeNode node = null;
        string f = string.Empty;

        int p = path.IndexOf('/');

        if (p == -1)
        {
            f = path;
            path = "";
        }
        else
        {
            f = path.Substring(0, p);
            path = path.Substring(p + 1, path.Length - (p + 1));
        }

        node = null;

        foreach (TreeNode item in nodeList)
        {
            if (item.Text == f)
            {
                node = item;                   
            }
        }

        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new TreeNode(f);
            nodeList.Add(node);
        }

        if (path != "")
        {
            CreateTree(node.Nodes, path, name);
        }
    }
```

Populate list and create tree:

```
List<Item> list = new List<Item>();

list.Add(new Item { Name = "Parent", Path = "1" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/2" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "son", Path = "1/3" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/2/4" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/2/5" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "son", Path = "1/3/6" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "son", Path = "1/3/7" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "son", Path = "1/2/5/8" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/2/5/9" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/3/6/10" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "son", Path = "1/3/6/11" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/3/7/12" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/3/7/13" });
list.Add(new Item { Name = "daughter", Path = "1/3/7/14" });


foreach (Item line in list)
{
    CreateTree(treeView1.Nodes, line.Path, line.Name);
}

class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine but instead of last number of path I want to show name. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function did everything right, but it needed  little modification. I've replaced:

```
foreach (TreeNode item in nodeList)
        {
            if (item.Text == f)
            {
                node = item;                   
            }
        }
```

to

```
foreach (TreeNode item in nodeList)
            {
                if (item.Tag.ToString() == f)
                {
                    node = item;
                }
            }
```

and

```
if (node == null)
        {
            node = new TreeNode(f);
            nodeList.Add(node);
        }
```

to

```
if (node == null)
            {                
                node = new TreeNode(name);
                node.Tag = f;
                nodeList.Add(node);
            }
```

I hope it helps :)